# Get length of every element in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get length of every element in array

my code is

```
var a = "Hello world" ; 
var chars = a.split(' ');
```

so I will have an array of

```
chars = ['Hello' , 'world'] ;
```

but how I can get length of each word like this ?

```
Hello = 5 
world = 5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use map Array function:

```
var lengths = chars.map(function(word){
 return word.length
})
```

Answer (score 6):

ES6 is now widely available (2019-10-03) so for completeness — you can use the [arrow operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with `.map()`

```
var words = [ "Hello", "World", "I", "am", "here" ];
words.map(w => w.length);
> Array [ 5, 5, 1, 2, 4 ]
```

or, very succinctly

```
"Hello World I am here".split(' ').map(w => w.length)
> Array [ 5, 5, 1, 2, 4 ]
```

Comment: Or you can do it with array comprehension: `[for (word of words) word.length]`

Comment: @friedi - nice also! but [MDN warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions#wikiArticle) "Non-standard. Do not use!" ... this was removed from the ES6 draft; it could conceivably end up in ES7, and MDN compatibility chart shows only Firefox currently supports it. Still cool.

Comment: I'm lost! OK, so "words" is an array, and "words.map" gets the length of each word, which it stored in an array as "> Array[5,5,1,2,4]. But how to access the cells of that latter array? What is it's name?

Comment: @Cristofayre - in my answer the examples are from typing in the browser console, and I'm not assigning the result of `words.map` to anything. You would want to do something like `let wordLengths = words.map(w => w.length);` then you an access the latter array as `wordLengths[i]` just like any other array. In the browser console I use `var` but in actual js code I _never_ use it; I use `const` and `let`.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to use .length property of a string:

```
   for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
    console.log(chars[i].length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a results object (so you have the key, "hello", and the length, 5):

```
function getLengthOfWords(str) {
    var results = {}; 
    var chars = str.split(' ');
    chars.forEach(function(item) {
        results[item] = item.length;
    });
    return results;
}

getLengthOfWords("Hello world"); // {'hello': 5, 'world': 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var words = ['Hello', 'world'];

var lengths = words.map(function(word) {
  return word + ' = ' + word.length;
});

console.log(lengths);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), if you want to keep the words, and the length you can do it like this:

```
var a = "Hello world" ; 
var chars = a.split(' ');

    var words = [];
    chars.forEach(function(str) { 
        words.push([str, str.length]);
    });
```

You can then access both the size and the word in the array.

Optionally you could have a little POJO object, for easier access:

```
var a = "Hello world" ; 
var chars = a.split(' ');

var words = [];
chars.forEach(function(str) { 
    words.push({word: str, length: str.length});
});
```

Then you can access them like:

```
console.log(words[0].length); //5
console.log(words[0].word); //"Hello"
```

Or using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the same POJO:

```
var words = chars.map(function(str) { 
    return {word: str, length: str.length};
});
```