# How to get each element's length in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, function

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>This is the 3rd html</title>
 <!--Wei Wu section A-->
 <h1>This program wraps your text</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 /*function arrayToStr(){
  var word = []

 }*/
 function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
   arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator); //注意这儿能不能用
   document.write(arrayOfStrings + "<br>");
   /*'The original string is: "' + stringToSplit + '"';
   'The separator is: "' + separator + '"')
   'The array has ' + arrayOfStrings.length + ' elements: ' + arrayOfStrings.join(' / '))*/
 }
 function longestWord(){
  longest = arrayOfStrings[0].length;
  for (i=1; i<arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
  
  if(longest<arrayOfStrings[i].length){
   longest = arrayOfStrings[i].length;
  }
  else{
   longest=longest;
  }
 }
 document.write(longest + "<br>");
 }

 function splitUp(){
  //arrayOfStrings = splitString(word," ");
  howLong = arrayOfStrings[0].length;
  for(i=0; i< arrayOfStrings.length;){
   if (howLong <longest){
    document.write(arrayOfStrings[i] + ' ');
    howLong = howLong + 1 + arrayOfStrings[i+1].length;
    i++;
   }
   else if (howLong = longest){
    document.write(arrayOfStrings[i] + "<br>");
    howLong = arrayOfStrings[i+1].length;
    i++;
   }
   else{
    document.write("<br>" + arrayOfStrings[i] + " ");
    howLong = arrayOfStrings[i].length + 1 + arrayOfStrings[i+1].length;
    i++;
   }
 }
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  word = [];
  word = prompt("type a very long sentence that you want me to deal with: ");
  splitString(word, " ");
  longestWord();
  splitUp();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi all,

Thank you for your help. This assignment is to wrap text:
1. Includes an HTML input field for users to enter a string directly into a web page with an HTML button to execute the JavaScript. (I'll just skill the button part and to that later)
2. Includes a function that breaks the input string into individual words.
3. Includes a function to determine the longest single word in the input
string (may be grouped with the previous function).
4. Includes a function to write the words of the string directly out to a web page, laid out so that no single line is longer than the longest word in the string.

I think for the first three, mine works well, but for the function that I wrote for the 4th part, it didn't work... I can not cut work into all those segment that a shorter than the longest word..

Comment: hope this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399786/get-length-of-every-element-in-array-javascript

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code with some input I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

There is a point in your code where you're trying to access the length property of an object (string/array) that doesn't exist.

You should try running the code with a debugger/breakpoints/logging to see which of the calls to `<string-or-array>.length` is failing. Consider logging the input/output of each stage to see if it matches your expectations.

As an aside, defining word boundaries with a separator is problematic, although this may not be important for your assignment. If you are interested, take a look at regular expressions for an alternative to finding word boundaries.